# Overlay barplot with negative binomial/poisson distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I overlay my barplot on real data with the estimated negative binomial density function using the same mean and variance?

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

temp <- data.table(cbind(V1=c(1,2,3,4,5,9), N=c(50,40,30,20,10,2)))

ggplot(temp, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 2.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 100, 200, max(temp$N))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 100, 200, max(temp$V1))) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()
  )
```

I tried to add `stat_function(fun = dnbinom, args = list(size=1, mu = mean(temp$V1)), color="red")` but all I see is a red line on the abscissa. Same for `dpois` (with `lambda=mean(temp$V1)`) and `dnorm` (with `mean = mean(temp$V1), sd = sd(temp$V1)`).

Maybe my parametrization is wrong?

Comment: Of the three distribution functions you mention, only `dnorm()` takes the parameters `mean` and `sd`. Have you tried changing the arguments in your `stat_function()` call to match the requirments of `dnbinom()`?

Comment: Good hint, thanks. I in fact missed the parametrization for these distributions. Now at least I have a red line.

Comment: The flatness of the red line is likely an issue of scale -- your density function layer should have a maximum y value less than 1, while your histogram layer has a maximum of 50. One solution could be rescaling your histogram using something like `aes(x=V1, y= N/sum(temp$N))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mmk is correct: normalization is the key. Here's how you can achieve what you want:

```
#simplest normalization
temp$Nmod <- temp$N / sum(temp$N)
#alternative normalization
#temp$Nmod <- temp$N / sqrt(sum(temp$N * temp$N))
temp$pois <- dpois(temp$V1, lambda = mean(temp$V1))
temp$nbinom <- dnbinom(temp$V1, mu = mean(temp$V1), size = 1)
ggplot(temp, aes(x=V1, y= Nmod)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 2.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
       panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = pois), col = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = nbinom), col = "blue")
```

[image]